# ORDER BY the IN value list position

Tags: elasticsearch

I need to build elasticsearch query with sorting by field value positioning from an array.

Similar to MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM `comments` ORDER BY FIELD(`id`,'17','3','5','12') DESC, id DESC;
```

or Postgres:

```
SELECT * FROM comments
LEFT JOIN unnest('{12,5,3,17}'::int[]) WITH ORDINALITY t(id, ord) USING (id) ORDER  BY t.ord, id DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for custom sorting in elasticsearch

 it is possible to achieve it via painless script

 here is what I do

```
PUT my_test
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "animal": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Populate docs

```
POST my_test/_doc
{
  "animal": "mouse"
}
POST my_test/_doc
{
  "animal": "cat"
}
POST my_test/_doc
{
  "animal": "dog"
}
```

Custom sort

```
GET my_test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },

    "sort": {
        "_script": {
            "type": "number",
            "script": {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "if(params.scores.containsKey(doc['animal'].value)) { return params.scores[doc['animal'].value];} return 100000;",
                "params": {
                    "scores": {
                        "dog": 0,
                        "cat": 1,
                        "mouse": 2
                    }
                }
            },
            "order": "asc"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to compliment the answer above.

You can combine the approach to promote some items to the top and keep the origin sorting by relevance for all other items of the search result.

```
"sort": {
    "_script": {
        "type": "number",
        "script": {
            "lang": "painless",
            "source": "if(params.scores.containsKey(doc['sku'].value)) { return params.scores[doc['sku'].value];} return 10",
            "params": {
                "scores": {
                    "3JK76": 0,
                    "8UF78": 1
                }
            }
        },
        "order": "asc"
    },
    "_score": { "order": "desc" }
}
```